# Android's version of C#'s Console.WriteLine?

Tags: android

In Android, what is the best way to write to the console. In C# I'd use either Log4Net or just Console.Write

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the help pages for [Android.Util.Log](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html).

You can use:

```
Log.v("MyActivity", "Verbose output");
Log.d("MyActivity", "Debug output");
Log.e("MyActivity", "Error output");
Log.i("MyActivity", "Information output");
Log.w("MyActivity", "Warning output");
Log.wtf("MyActivity", "WTF output"); // This isn't a joke :)
```

Comment: Seriously not a joke - wtf: What a Terrible Failure

Answer (score 2):

For simple debugging, the standard Java way suffices:

```
System.out.println("Message");
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Dan Dyer mentions, `System.out.println(yourString);` will do fine. But don't expect it to show up in the console running the emulator. You will have to look for your output in the logcat. (There is a tab for it in eclipse if that's your development environment.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to Debug in Eclipse and how to use the [ADB](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb) and [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20120618172953/http://developer.android.com:80/guide/developing/tools/ddms.html) tools.

In order to get more details about an exception/force close you need to look for a view in Eclipse called [Logcat](https://web.archive.org/web/20100324231958/http://developer.android.com:80/intl/de/guide/developing/debug-tasks.html)(you will find in the [DDMS](https://web.archive.org/web/20170825232742/http://www.brighthub.com:80/mobile/google-android/articles/25023.aspx) perspective) there you will find a detailed traceback when/what and on what line is the issue.

For this you should read a complete article about [Debugging in Android using Eclipse](http://www.droidnova.com/debugging-in-android-using-eclipse,541.html)

[image]
<sub>(source: [droidnova.com](http://www.droidnova.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/debugging-3.gif))</sub>